# Changing a project name

Tags: project, rename, sphero-api

I have created an app for sphero.
The problem is that i started by opening the sphero sample program ButtonDrive and worked with that as a base. Now i want to change the name of the project and the apk.
I have tried right-clicking the project and renaming it that way, and for the main project that works, however when i run the project as an application unto my nexus 7 is just comes up and says:
" Unfortunately, Button Drive has stopped"

So why doesn't this work?
The tablet clearly thinks the project is still called Button Drive but where in the code do i have to change this to make it work?

or is it just not possible to change the name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-clicked on the project in the project navigator did you click rename in the main dropdown, or did you click on "Rename Application Package" within the android tools sub-menu? You should be using the later option.

Also verify that the AndroidManifest.xml Label field is correct, or if it is pointing to a value in strings.xml within res/values verify that the application name is correct.